# Chromium freezes intermittent at each few seconds

Tags: chromium, 19.10

After a update few days ago, the Chromium freezes intermittent at each X seconds (maybe 60) but not for all webpages. I was using ubuntu 18.04. I upgraded to 19.10 hopping that the problem went away but not. Remains.

For example, in youtube, the audio of the movie keeps playing well, but the video and the entire webpage frezes. Facebook also shows this problem even when not reproducing any video. This problem does not happen with Firefox or any other programs. For example, VLC does not appear to have this problem.

Chromium Versão 79.0.3945.79 (Compilação oficial) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 19.10 (64 bits)

Any ideias to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: There have been tons of complaints about this release of Chromium on the Linux Mint forums. Can you run another update - Chromium should be on version 79.0.3945.88 now.

Comment: I did and there is no newer package of Chromium (at least automatically).

Comment: I had switched to Chrome (due to DRM issues) a few weeks ago and I haven't experienced any of the freeze issues that have plagued Chromium and other Chrome-based browsers, although I have no idea if this new version is the savior. I'm not sure why the repos haven't gotten the new version yet.

Comment: I tried: sudo snap install chromium --beta but it installs a new package ignoring all configurations and settings from current chromium installed.

Comment: That's because of snap's sandboxing. I would wait until a fix is published; like I said, I have no idea if the .88 version is the true "fix" or now.

Comment: This happens to me in Lubuntu 16.04 both with Chromium and Brave. So it's likely a Chromium issue.

Comment: is it possible to remove the update of chromium and return to the previous version?

Comment: Now the chromium is Versão 79.0.3945.117  installed using snap. It is even worst! Cannot save files to several folders (even it it i made chomd -c777 /directory)!

Comment: Chrome is now with the exact same problems. But it is something wrong with 19.10 because now it is also Firefox that has some graphical strange errors. I also am now unable to run ktorrent and skype.

Comment: i am unable to run lsb-release! Keeps saying that it does not found it but it is installed.

Comment: i gave up and made a fresh installation of 19.10 and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here. Ubuntu 19.10 destroyed my notebook. Freezes mouse on chromium with each new click. You can't use the browser. Ubuntu 19.10 is horrible for GATEWAY N570. Maximum regret to update.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and for your interest in this site.  However, your post does not answer the question that was asked and so should not be posted as an answer.  If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](/questions/ask).

Comment: I agree. There are some seriuos problems with 19.10. I keept making updates to see if they are fixed.